# Enable a button basing on multiple form values being equal

Tags: 7, forms

I would not like users to be able to submit a form until:

1. All fields are filled out
2. The password and confirm password fields are equal

I can do this with JavaScript, potentially, but then the JavaScript code would managing some states and the PHP code would manage other states. It seems messy.

This is the code I wrote.

```
'disabled' => array(
// disable button if missing required fields
        array(
          ':input[name="field1"]' => array('value' => ''),
        ),
        array(
          ':input[name="field2"]' => array('value' => ''),
        ),
        array(
          ':input[name="password"]' => array('value' => ''),
        ),
        array(
          ':input[name="confirm_password"]' => array('value' => ''),
        ),
      ),

      // only enable the button when passwords are ==
'enabled' => array(
        array(
          ':input[name="password"]' => array('value' => ':input[name="confirm_password"]')
        )
      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'array('value' => ':input[name="confirm_password"]')
```

This means the value equals the literal string ":input[name="confirm_password"]".
As far as I know, `#states` can't check if the value of two fields are the same.

> I can do this with JavaScript, potentially, but then the JavaScript
>   code would managing some states and the PHP code would manage other
>   states. It seems messy.

Here is a way that may seem less messy. Use a hidden `compare_passwords` field whose value will indicate whether the `password` and `confirm_password` fields have the same value:

```
$form['compare_passwords'] = array('#type' => 'hidden', '#default_value' => 'fail');
```

Use the value of that field in the `#states` array for your button.

```
':input[name="compare_passwords"]' => array('value' => 'match')
```

Write some JavaScript that changes the value of `compare_passwords` whenever the value of `password` or `confirm_password` changes (use [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of [bind()](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) if your site uses jQuery 1.7+):

```
var password_selector = ':input[name="password"]';
var confirm_selector = ':input[name="confirm_password"]';
var compare_selector = ':input[name="compare_passwords"]';
$(password_selector + ',' + confirm_selector).bind("change paste keyup blur", function () {
  if ($(password_selector).val() == $(confirm_selector).val()) {
    $(compare_selector).val('match').change();
  } else {
    $(compare_selector).val('fail').change();
  }
});
```

By the way, you can use `'!value'` to put all your *"does not equal empty string"* conditions under "enabled", using the Boolean "AND" structure. The Boolean "OR" structure, which is wrapping each condition in its own array, is harder to understand if you aren't familiar with `#states`.

```
// Only enable the button when all fields have a value and passwords match.
// The value in "compare_passwords" is dynamically updated by my_script.js
//  whenever the user types inside the password or compare_password fields.
$form['my_button']['#states'] = array(
  'enabled' => array(
    ':input[name="field1"]' => array('!value' => ''),
    ':input[name="field2"]' => array('!value' => ''),
    ':input[name="password"]' => array('!value' => ''),
    ':input[name="confirm_password"]' => array('!value' => ''),
    ':input[name="compare_passwords"]' => array('value' => 'match'),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thats a clever approach. Having dynamic values only on the left side of a bool like field feels like an incomplete api to me, but thanks for the tip on how to handle it.

Comment: Thanks. I feel the same about the API. In fact, the documentation for [drupal_process_states](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7.x) mentions that there are some states that are not fully implemented. For example the `valid` and `invalid` states combined with a [password_confirm field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#password_confirm) looked promising, but it doesn't look like `valid` has been implemented for `#states` (turns out the `password_confirm` field doesn't implement it either).